# How should I handle checked exceptions in Spring's JavaConfig?

Tags: spring

I am moving over some existing xml configuration to Java configuration for Spring.  During this process, I have encountered some transferred Java code that throws a checked `Exception`.

```
@Bean
public PoolDataSource myDataSource()
{
    final PoolDataSource dataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    dataSource.setConnectionPoolName("myDataSourcePoolName"); // throws SQLException
    return dataSource;
}
```

I was wondering how I should handle it, and whether or not the Spring developers had any *'best practices'* in mind.

Should I mark the method with a `throws` clause (which would propagate up any `@Import` chain) or should I handle it method with a `try`-`catch` block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, you should simply declare any checked exceptions in the `throws` clause of the `@Bean` method.

I am not certain what you're referring to with regard to "propagating up any `@Import` chain"; the `throws` clause will of course require any dependent `@Bean` methods to in turn declare a `throws` clause containing that exception, but when it comes to actual exception propagation at container bootstrap time, the exception will be handled by the Spring container in just the same way that exceptions thrown from beans configured in Spring XML are handled.`@Import` should be an orthogonal concern here.

Comment: Straight from the developer himself.  Thanks, you have sufficiently answered my question.  That no, there is no 'right' way to do it.